# Dom issues when using jquery filter plugin

Tags: jquery, dom, filter, edit-in-place

I am using https://github.com/chromawoods/instaFilta for filter a table

The table has dynamic row insertion using ajax and each row cells can be updated using edit in place using:

https://github.com/itinken/jinplace

Now when i add a new row and then edit for example "title" to "Linux" and then try to filter, it will show the row which has "Linux" and if i again change "Linux" to "Unix" and again try filter without reloading the page from server - the word "Unix" will be changed to old data - here, "Linux" and the filter will not work and when i reload the page, the title is showed correctly "Unix".

So the dom gets updated from stale data when i try filtering.

Code:

//In place edit

```
$(document).on('click', 'span.editable', function(event) {
    $('.editable').jinplace({
        url: '/onit/web/data-updater.php',
        textOnly: false,
        placeholder: '',
        okButton: '',
        cancelButton: ''
    })
    .on('jinplace:done', function(event, data) {
       console.log('Successful! New value is', data);
    });
});
```

and this is the code for

// Filter

```
$(document).on('click', '#filter-me', function(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    $('#filter-me').instaFilta({
        //scope: '.content-wrapper',
        //targets: '.instafilta-target',
        caseSensitive: false,
        markMatches: true,
        beginsWith: false,
        matchCssClass: 'instafilta-match',
        itemsHideEffect: 'slideUp',
        itemsHideDuration:300
    });
});
```

How can i make the filter update when a row is updated using edit-in-place or how can i tell instaFilta to get the latest dom?

Comment: i used this plugin :

https://github.com/awbush/jquery-fastLiveFilter 

from Anthony Bush and everything working great now!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("#filter-me").instaFilta({
        scope: "#ex1" 
    });
});
```

to initialize filtering after ajax end